# Using font package with Storybook React

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, storybook

I'm using CRA & Storybook with an installed font [typeface-roboto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeface-roboto). This works fine in dev, the font shows up in Storybook. However when I build Storybook and serve it as a static app Storybook is looking for the fonts in the wrong place.

I'm installing the font as so `yarn add typeface-roboto` and then importing it into my **.storybook/preview.js** file;

```
import 'typeface-roboto'
```

When I build storybook, and then serve it with [serve](https://github.com/zeit/serve) Storybook is trying to load the font from **localhost:5000/static/css/static/media/roboto.woff** whereas the font is located at **static/media**, without the additional **static/css** subfolders.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with CRA or Storybook, or even webpack, and wht additional configuration I may need to add to fix it.

Here's a [storybook issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/9564) linking to a repo recreating the issue.